# CakeEmail: no render Flash Message

Tags: cakephp

In CakePhp 2.0, using CakeEmail new Component  seems to not output flash message:
In my controller I put:

```
$email = new CakeEmail(array('log'=>true));
$email->transport('Debug');
```

and in my view

```
 echo $this->Session->flash('email');
```

But nothing is printed out.
Has that function (flash) been removed in 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is flash function in cakephp 2.0 for details check it here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html

If you want to get ur flash message in your view you have to first set it in your Controller action.

```
//controller
$this->Session->setFlash('email');

//view
echo $this->Session->flash();
```

// The above will output.

```
<div id="flashMessage" class="message">
'email'.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

none of the cake email libs or components or  transport classes touch the session or write any such flash content. they never did as far is I know.
but they return the email content as array for the DebugTransport.

so you would want to fetch the returned array and log it away:

```
$res = $this->Email->send();
$this->Session->setFlash($res ? 'Email sent' : 'Email not sent');
```

or sth like that.

Comment: They do in 1.3. if you send the mail as debug they would save on a session var instead and you don't need server for testing it. http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1635/Debugging-Emails Don't know if it works on 2.0

Comment: as I just said, there absolutely no access to the session anywhere in the email in cake2.x - so logically that can't happen. so use the new "better" way of debugging emails by using the returned data.

Comment: Got it. I was anwsering for your "they never did as far is I know", as it did at some point, now I understand you are talking about 2.x only.

Comment: right :) 1.x is too long ago to remember. if you want to display flash messages for it, you will need to do that manually now (as outlined above using `$this->Session->setFlash($myStringToDisplayInView);`

Comment: He has specified 'log' => true in config which will already log the info, no point logging it again as per your example.

Comment: true :) the above example should make more sense, then in combination with log=>true. although if in controller context, he could use the component here instead, just as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Cake 2.x the debug transport doesn't set the email content in session. Just check the return value, `$contents = $email->send();`. $contents will contain the headers and message so use them as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = $Email->send();

$response['headers']; // headers as string
$response['message']; // message body with attachments

$this->Session->setFlash($response['headers'].$response['message']);
```

Make sure you have the following in your layout file.

```
echo $this->Session->flash();
```